# Simple Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Problem: Show that $f_n^2$ converges to $f^2$ uniformly whenever $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on a compact metric space $K$ converging uniformly to a function $f$.

This seems almost too simple so I want to check my proof: We know
$$
|f_n^2(x)-f^2(x)|=|f_n(x)-f(x)| \; |f_n(x)+f(x)|
$$
As $f_n \to f$ uniformly and the $f_n$ are continuous, we know that $f$ is continuous. Since $f$ is continuous on the compact space $K$, we know that $f$ is bounded, say $|f(x)| \leq B$. We know also that the $f_n$ are continuous on the compact space $K$, so that $|f_n(x)| \leq B_n$ for some $M_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $M_n=\max\{B_n,B\}$. As $f_n \to f$ uniformly, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon /(2M_N$). Then
$$
|f_n^2(x)-f^2(x)|=|f_n(x)-f(x)| \; |f_n(x)+f(x)| < \epsilon/(2M_N) \cdot 2M_N = \epsilon
$$

Comment: The last few sentences appear problematic.

Comment: You have a typo in the first instance of $M_n$ which should be $B_n$.  When you write "there is a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon /(2M_N)$," you don't say for what $n$ this holds (or for what $x$, but on account of uniform convergence I assume that's all $x\in K$).  The same issues exist for the final displayed equation.  In your shoes I would show that because of uniform convergence to $f$ which is bounded, we have $|f_n(x)|<M'$ for all $x\in K$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and some real $M'$.

Comment: @ForgotALot This was the issue I was concerned about. But I think I see the argument now to fix this. As $f_n \to f$ and $f$ is bounded, $|f_n-f|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. But we know that $|f|<M$ for some $M$ then $|f_n| \leq M+\epsilon$ for $n>N$. But then Taking $M'=\max\{M_1,M_2,\cdots,M_{n-1},M+\epsilon\}$, where $M_i$ is the bound for $f_i$, we know that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and then changing what needs to be changed, the result follows. Feel free to post your comment again as a solution and I will accept it.